# Скрыть один из div'ов с одинаковыми class'ами

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть несколько `div'ов` с одинаковыми `class'ами`, как можно скрыть пару `div'ов` из них? `id` не могу добавить.

```
<div buttontype="1" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="2" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="3" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="4" class="item-transparent"></div>
```

`Div'ы` различаются только buttontype.

Comment: Скрыть как? При каких условиях? Один или несколько? Если несколько, то как отличать какие именно нужно скрыть?

Comment: Вопрос дополнил, различаются лишь buttontype'ами.

Comment: Скрывать при наведение или клику или ещё какому-то событию? Скрывать тот на котором курсор был?

Comment: Нет, просто надо скрыть и все. Условий нету, просто скрыть. Например через display:none & visibility: hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи **JQ**

```js
$('input').on('click',function(){
  var dataType = $(this).data('type');
  $('.item-transparent[buttontype="'+dataType+'"]').hide();
});
```

```css
.item-transparent {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  background: red;
}

.item-transparent[buttontype] {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-transparent"></div>
<div class="item-transparent"></div>
<div class="item-transparent"></div>

<div buttontype="1" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="2" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="3" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="4" class="item-transparent"></div>

<input type="button" value="hide 1" data-type="1" />
<input type="button" value="hide 2" data-type="2" />
<input type="button" value="hide 3" data-type="3" />
<input type="button" value="hide 4" data-type="4" />
```

При помощи **CSS**

```css
.item-transparent {display: block; width: 100px; height: 30px; background: red; margin: 0 0 5px;}
.item-transparent[buttontype] {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="item-transparent"></div>
<div class="item-transparent"></div>
<div class="item-transparent"></div>

<div buttontype="1" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="2" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="3" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="4" class="item-transparent"></div>
```

Comment: Если хочу скрыть определенный buttontype? Например buttontype="1" и buttontype="3"

Comment: @АндрейЗахаров, дополнил ответ, добавив JQ. А чтобы скрыть те, что вы написали, просто в CSS написать `.item-transparent[buttontype="1"], .item-transparent[buttontype="3"] {display: none;}`

Comment: Нашел способ выборки. Спасибо `.item-transparent[buttontype$="4"] {display: none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать через псевдокласс вот так:

```
<div class="list">
 <div buttontype="1" class="item-transparent"></div>
 <div buttontype="2" class="item-transparent"></div>
 <div buttontype="3" class="item-transparent"></div>
 <div buttontype="4" class="item-transparent"></div>
</div>

.list:nth-child(1):{
      display:none;
}
.list:nth-child(3):{
      display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.item-transparent {display: block; width: 100px; height: 30px; background: red; margin: 0 0 5px;}
.item-transparent[buttontype$="1"] {display: none;}
```

```html
<div class="item-transparent"></div>
<div class="item-transparent"></div>
<div class="item-transparent"></div>

<div buttontype="1" class="item-transparent"></div>
<div buttontype="2" class="item-transparent"></div>
```